# Powershell - adding multiple Get-Date commands into variable

Tags: powershell

So I am trying to get the date 3 months back using the Powershell command Get-Date.  However, when I try to add multiple get-dates in one line it errors out or doesn't give me the results I'm looking for.

The End result I'm trying to get is `$checkDate = 6-7-2016`

I've tried this, but it doesn't really work:

```
$checkDate = (Get-Date).month -3 "-" (Get-Date).day "-" (Get-Date).year
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?  I'm newer to Powershell and not exactly sure how to concatenate properly.

I'm using PS 4.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are trying to do is format a calculated date. So let's start with calculating the date:

```
(Get-Date).AddMonths(-3)
```

That gets you today's date minus 3 months. Next you want to format it in a specific manner. That being Month-Day-Year. That can be done as such:

```
(Get-Date).AddMonths(-3).ToString("M-d-yyyy")
```

That results in:

```
6-7-2016
```